# ¿Como atrapar el error unique constraint en metodo persist?

Tags: java, jpa

estoy usando netbeans en una aplicación que usa JPA+EclipseLink, e intentando que cuando el metodo "persist" genera error, pueda atraparlo desde la clase y manejarlo.
El error del que se trata es por clave duplicada y por alguna razon, no logro 
atraparlo, como si el "catch" no funcionara: 
    `@Override
    public void insertPtovta(Ptovta ptovta) throws ServletException {
        try {
            em.persist(ptovta);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.debug(e);
            throw new ServletException("Ocurrio un Error en metodo buscaUsuario !", e);
        }
    }`

Este es parte del mensaje que lanza netbeans:

> Advertencia:   Local Exception Stack: 
>   Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «unq_ptovta_0»
>     Detail: Ya existe la llave (idtipo, letra, ptovta)=(2, A, 1).
>   Error Code: 0
>   Call: INSERT INTO ptovta (COPIAS, DESTINO, IMPRIME, LETRA, PTOVTA, RENGLON, TIPONUM, ULTIMO, idtipo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>       bind => [9 parameters bound]
>   Query: InsertObjectQuery(kompass.coopkit.model.Ptovta@1d5)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)

En el log de glassfish se aprecia claramente el mensaje del error.
Alguna idea de como poder atraparlo ?
Desde ya muy agradecido!
Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la solucion agregando la siguiente linea:

> em.flush();

finalmente el metodo quedo:

```
 @Override
public void insertPtovta(Ptovta ptovta) throws ServletException {
    try {
        em.persist(ptovta);
        em.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug(e);
        throw new ServletException("Ocurrio un Error en metodo Insert Punto de Venta !", e);
    }
}
```